# Is there a way to introduce a random size for children particles?

Tags: particles

When I create a particle system using *object* or *group* rendering I often want to make the particles' sizes slightly randomized.  I accomplish this by changing the *random size* spinner under *physics*.

[image]

Here is an example:
[image]

But then, to save memory and add more particles, I usually use *interpolated* children particles.

[image]

But using children particles seems to ignore the random size spinner.

[image]

The particles are now all the same size.  The value of the aforementioned *random size* no longer has any impact whatsoever on the look of the particles; and nothing I could find under the children settings has a similar effect to it.  All the random values on the *children* rollout just seem to change the location and/or rotation in some way or another, not the size.

**So how can I change the random size of the children particles?**

**Edit:**
In response to [Bithur's comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24454/is-there-a-way-to-introduce-a-random-size-for-children-particles?noredirect=1#comment36015_24454), this is what I get when I adjust the *length* and *threshold* settings:

[image]

As you can see, half of the particles are the normal height and half are scaled down a specific amount.  It's slightly better, but by no means a random scale.

Comment: play with length and threshold of children. Parents are not viewed by default.

Comment: In *Simple* mode there is an option under *Size* that says *Random*, so if you don't need to use *Interpolated* mode then that should work.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Unfortunately most of the time I need to use interpolated.

Comment: I tried it with just one particle, and all of the interpolated ones were different heights. I can't figure out why :/

Comment: @Bithur I tried that and it seems to just scale down half the particles to an exact amount.  See edit...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found what appears to be a solution, however it might be a bug/unexpected (or unsupported) behavior. What you do is you pretend you are going to use the *Simple* mode, set the random size, and then switch back to *Interpolated* mode. Some reason the random size data is "remembered" and now the particles are random sizes.

[image: Random Sizes]

This appears to render correctly, and changing other particle settings doesn't appear to affect it at all.

Comment: My hero! :) thx for this tip!

Comment: Wow, that is weird, thanks a ton!  Now if someone can figure out why that spinner is missing from the interpolated settings...

Comment: Hear hear! Seems like a very logical addition.